# extract a word found in a String []

Tags: c#, list

```
string [] leerArchivo;
```

good evening, i have to get a sub-string from a string. I have a file type `"string []"` that contains a string like this.

```
//start class ClassName xxxxx
```

where ClassName can be any name, then this is a description that does not interest me to capture, so if I need in the optener (ClassName)

thank you very much beforehand, I hope and make me understand.

Comment: im not sure what you want to do. do you want to get whatever is in the place of "ClassName"? you could use a simple Split() for that...

Comment: provided information is not enough...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you call the "Substring" method in which you specify the first and last indexes of the characters you want to get.

```
string input = "OneTwoThree";

//Get first three characters
string sub = input.Substring(0, 3);
```

The output would be just the first 3 letters (in this case "One").

You can also specify just the first index of and the method will take everything from that character onwards

```
string input = "OneTwoThree";
string sub = input.Substring(3);
```

the output in this case will be: "TwoThree"

but it looks like you want to get the name of a class, and there is a much simpler way to do that : 
`typeof(MyProgram).Name`

Hope it helps :)

Comment: thank you very much for the help, what happens is that it is an educational program for me. For if I am trying to make a counter rather rustic lines: p to regularly exercise

Comment: haha I didn't understand much of what you said but you're welcomed :)